# Link button color HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have quite a problem, I created a button that leads to an iTunes page.

When I did the CSS I had no problem until I noticed that I didnt link the button to the page. So when I did, I couldn't disable the underline of my text inside my button.

I worked my way through and now I'm stuck with a text that is not underlined and changes color when hovered as I wanted. Only thing is that the border doesn't change color at the same time as the text.

Example: I can hover (and thus change the color) my border without touching my text, and obviously this is not what I want.

Snippet :

```css
.navigation{
background-color:#C5C5C5;  
}

.btniTunes {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btniTunes:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #E80C7A;
  border: 1px solid #E80C7A;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btniTunes a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="bouttons">
    <div class="btnSite">
      TO THE SITE
    </div>
    <div class="btniTunes">
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/be/artist/pnl/id370571621"> TO THE ITUNES</a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

So basically, I want to have a button that links to a page, with black background, white text and border, that has the text and border color that changes to #E80C7A when hovered and without underline on the text.

Comment: You are missing closing brackets for your styles :)

Comment: [Specificity - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I know but i have them in my code don't worry, i just missed them with the copy paste :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are :)

Remove the padding from `.btniTunes` and add it to `.btniTunes a` and add `display: block;` to it.

```css
.btniTunes {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btniTunes:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #E80C7A;
  border: 1px solid #E80C7A;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btniTunes a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.btniTunes:hover a {
  color: #E80C7A;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="bouttons">
    <div class="btnSite">
      TO THE SITE
    </div>
    <div class="btniTunes">
      <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/be/artist/pnl/id370571621"> TO THE ITUNES</a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
The only thing is that when i hover on the boutton the text doesn't change color?

Comment: Edited :) Now it changes color :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just close the brackets in css:

```
.btniTunes {
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:10px 18px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.btniTunes:hover {
    background-color:black;
    color:#E80C7A;
    border:1px solid #E80C7A;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.btniTunes a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
}
```

and also if you want the `<a>` to cover the button, set its "display" to the block:

```
.btniTunes a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Of course you're right but that doesn't solve OP's problem.

What I understand is that:

- because you are using an anchor, only clicking on the text will take you to the itunes event
- because you apply the hover style change on the button, hovering anywhere in the button area (ie. not necessarily on the text) will trigger the color change.

The answer to this is either to use JavaScript to bind an action to a click on your button, or to make your anchor display:block and fit inside the whole area of your button.